# Creating a pie chart with unknown number of pies

Tags: python, python-3.x, legend, pie-chart

I am trying to create function which creates a pie chart. This pie chart can have n number of pies that's why I am taking function arguments as `*args`.
I found a way to create colors according to the number of input arguments in the function but I am stuck how to create legends in this function.

I want variable names as legends.
for example if, `pieChart(freigegebenCommands, KeinefreigegebenCommands )` is called then my legend should be

legends =['freigegebenCommands', 'KeinefreigegebenCommands']

How to implement this?

```
 def pieChart(*args):

    sizes = []
    for arg in args:
        sizes.append(len(arg))

    totalargs = len(args)    
    cs=cm.Set1(np.arange(totalargs)/totalargs)
    explode = (0.1, 0)  # explode 1st slice

    # Plot
    patches, texts, autotexts = plt.pie(sizes, explode=explode, colors=cs, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=140, radius = 2)

    ##HOW TO ADD LEGEND??
    #plt.legend(patches, legend, loc="best", bbox_to_anchor=(0.7, 1))
    plt.axis('equal')
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your args from a simple data type to tuples or any other suitable type (i.e dictionary)

```
input = [('slice_name', 1) ...]

pieChart(*input)
```

then inside your function just alter your for loops...

```
sizes = [len(x[1]) for x in args]
```

and get the legends from the first indexes